# Are there any reasonable clock-skew assumptions when using Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am building an identity generator like Twitter Snowflake hosted on Azure functions.  At the core of the identity is a timestamp in milliseconds.  I'd like to do some analysis of my collision probability with this scheme, but I think I need to take into account what the range of clock-skew I might be dealing with between compute instances.

Are there any reasonable assumptions I can make about clock-skew when using Azure Functions?  I realize at any point the possibility exists of a huge skew, but I'm curious if the Azure hosting infrastructure is using NTP or some other mechanism to synchronize compute instance clocks.  I'd be looking for an answer like:

> You have a 99.999% probability of a clock-skew within 5 seconds
>   between compute instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PM from the Functions team here.

The answer today is no. This isn't something we measure, and thus it'd be hard to make assumptions. I've created an issue to track this question, though I can't say when we'd get to the investigation: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/76

We are running on the same infra as Azure App Service (aka Azure Web Apps, aka Azure Websites). There are various community sourced blogs on the subject, which I can't officially say are true or not, but might give you a good idea in the mean time. It appears the sentiment is that you should assume large clock skew (which makes sense given we're not measuring it ourselves today).

Comment: Ok Chris, thanks for the response!  I will go with the assumption for now that the system time within an Azure function simply cannot be used reliably, and I'll have to instead make a request to a central time server to get the timestamp instead.